# nDepend locally does not seem to update results, but on build server it does

Tags: c#, ndepend

I have a large project that has nDepend running on it.  Locally it runs, but as I try to fix issues that were suggested, the queries do not seem to update.  They stay the same list of broken items that were there before.

And if I change a class name and file name, the same class still shows up in the results Query as an error, and when I double click on the error it message box shows me "the file cannot be found"

I've tried cleaning and rebuilding, changing to Release mode, manually deleting all files and rebuilding, restarting my computer, using the Visual Studio plugin, and using the VisualnDepend stand-alone app.  Nothing seems to make a difference.

Odd thing is that if I commit and run a build on our Jenkins instance, the report looks as I expected it to look.  (with things fixed, or renamed)

Is there some setting or process that I am missing locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you recompile your .NET projects with the changes, re-run NDepend analysis and changes are not reflected in the NDepend results, aren't you?

If yes, it means the analysis is analyzing some outdated assemblies/PDB, not touched by the re-compilation.

In "VisualNDepend > Analysis Error List" you can get the list of assemblies paths resolved and analyzed. If these assemblies are not updated when recompiling you might need to delete those, NDepend will try to find some more updated ones (assuming [your NDepend project references a VS solution and not directly somme assemblies](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/ndepend-assemblies-resolving))

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I had some "Corresponding PDB file not found..." and "PDB.. are not in-sync" warnings.  Rebuilding did not help, but with your guidance, I deleted all "bin" folders in my entire solution and it seems to be working now.  It takes 20 minutes to rebuild, so hopefully I dont have to do this often.